The solution of Green’s function in Dirac Delta ODE
I’m asking about the solution of the 2nd order Green’s function ODE:
$$\left( \dfrac{d^2}{d\eta^2}+ q^2 - 1  \right) g(\eta) = \delta(\eta-\tilde{\eta}) $$
Which is given by:
$$ g(\eta)  = c_1~ e^{t\sqrt{1-q^2}} + c_2~ e^{-t\sqrt{1-q^2}} $$
Where $t=\eta-\tilde{\eta}$. Is this solution correct? And if it’s right how is it derived?
Any help is appreciated!

@BenMcKay. So what about that solution of Green’s function?

you miss a step function term $\theta(t)$ (needed to give you the delta function upon differentiation)
$$g(\eta)  = c_1~ e^{t\sqrt{1-q^2}} + c_2~ e^{-t\sqrt{1-q^2}}+\frac{\sinh\left(t\sqrt{1-q^2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-q^2}}\theta(t).$$
to check that it solves the differential equation, use $\theta'(t)=\delta(t)$ and $f(t)\delta(t)=f(0)\delta(t)$, so that
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}f(t)\theta(t)=f''(t)\theta(t)+f'(0)\delta(t),\;\;\text{if}\;\;f(0)=0.$$
